# PHP Network error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple project with 1 javascript file and 1 php file. I am trying to use ajax to call some php code, which will then display text onto a lightbox. My problem is that I am receiving the following error:

This error points to my php file.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/folder/folder/dictionary.php"
```

I've checked (and double-checked) all my code, but I don't know how to fix this error.  Could someone please help me?  I will provide my JavaScript and PHP code below:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SearchField").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault(); 

        // grabs all post variables in the form
        var info = $(this).serialize();

        $.post('dictionary.php', info, function(data) {
            $('.DictionaryContentWrapper').append(data);
        });

        // prevent server from refreshing page
        return false;   
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
echo $input;
```

Directory Structure:

```
index.php
Widget
  - **input.js**
  - getURL.php
  - **dictionary.php**
lightbox
  - lightbox.css
  - lightbox.js
```

Comment: what are you files called? and what is the directory structure?

Comment: Are you running this locally off your desktop or do you have a web server somewhere?

Comment: I have provided the directory structure above, I have also highlighted the files which I have provided code for.

Comment: I am running this locally on a wampserver on my laptop.

Comment: @mpm, "code.php" was meant to be dictionary.php.  I have changed that at the top.

Comment: give us the exact error message you are getting. i see no "folder" folder in the directory you detailed.

Comment: @mpm, I have made the changes

Comment: Have you tried pointing your browser to http://localhost/Widget/dictionary.php?  Maybe it'd be in your best interest to use absolute paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use the absolute path relative to the root of your web-server.

Something like:

```
$.post('/Widget/dictionary.php', info, function(data) {
```

However, that assumes that your `index.php` resides in the root directory of the website - `http://localhost/index.php` - but that is not very clear from the information you have posted: The error message does not seem to fit the directory structure.

**Edit:** If you are calling your script from your `index.php`, you can also use:

```
$.post('Widget/dictionary.php', info, function(data) {    // path relative to index.php
```

Comment: The "index.php" file is located in the folder "Final Dictionary Widget", which is located in the localhost

Comment: @JaPerk14 You should post a clearer directory structure in your question, but in this case, the absolute path would be `/Final Dictionary Widget/Widget/dictionary.php`. I would however get rid of the spaces in the path.